# How to change button background color from lime green back to default setting?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to get the background button color to change from lime green back to its original color. I have been given a way to accomplish this for now, but it seems there has to be a more efficient way of doing this.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var productInfoButton = app.createButton("Products").setId('productInfoButton');

  var handlerL = app.createServerClickHandler('prodCompleteHandlerL');
  var productCompleteCheckBox = app.createCheckBox().setId("productCompleteCheckBox")
  .setName("productCompleteCheckBox");
  productCompleteCheckBox.addClickHandler(handlerL);
  handlerL.addCallbackElement(productInfoButton);

  app.add(productInfoButton);
  app.add(productCompleteCheckBox);

  return app;
}

function prodCompleteHandlerL(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
if(e.parameter.productCompleteCheckBox == 'true'){
  app.getElementById('productInfoButton').setStyleAttribute('background', 'lime')
}else{
  app.getElementById('productInfoButton').setStyleAttribute('background', 'url("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/211279/hborder.png") repeat-x 0px -27px')
}
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Try `.setStyleAttribute('background', 'auto');`.

Comment: @flem : this doesn't seem to work... have you tested it ?

Comment: I think it's because of `url("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/211279/hborder.png")`. I believe those are stripped out by Google. Try another color name instead.

Comment: @flem : The ('background', 'auto') is not working for me either.  Please let me know if you find any other solution.

Comment: @Frederic the URL solution works fine, the question is about finding a simpler / more straightforward solution...

Comment: I don't use google apps scripts but I assume you could add window.test=app.getElementById('productInfoButton').getStyleAttribute('background');
before
app.getElementById('productInfoButton').setStyleAttribute('background', 'lime') and then change app.getElementById('productInfoButton').setStyleAttribute('background', 'url("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/211279/hborder.png") repeat-x 0px -27px')
to
app.getElementById('productInfoButton').setStyleAttribute('background', window.test)

Answer (score 0):

Changing classes instead of changing background option directly is more reliable approach.

Switch the css class with background parameter in your handler function.

```
function clickHandler (e) {
    e.target.className = 'lime';
}

function prodCompleteHandler (e) {    
    e.target.className = 'standart'
}
```

Here is the code example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ysaxv/